# Find mean value in pandas by using groupby but have a problem

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, range

I would like to find the mean value in the range such as

```
Time           b
1              10
2              32
3              34
4               0
5              63
6              94
7              93
8              39
9               0
10            190 
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

I want to find the mean value of b in Time 1 to 3, 4 to 6, 7 to 9, ...

This is information I want to calculate:
[Info1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIe1h.png)

I want to find mean value for b from 0 to 6436801 in the certain range, 28800, so I try using

`df.groupby(pd.cut(df["b"],np.arange(0,6436801,28800))).mean()`

But it turns out like this:

[Info2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COrll.jpg)

Do you have other methods to deal with this kind of stuff? Or my code is wrong? 
Please suggest.

Comment: I am guessing that u are looking for  rolling mean. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the mean of every 3 rows,

```py
df_means = df.groupby( np.arange(len(df.Time))//3 ).mean()
```